# Visual Studio 2013 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer' is not defined

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

OK - I have been at this for hours now...

Using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938

Language: VB
Project Type: ASP.Net website project
Target Framework: 4.5.1

I have the following line declared in an .ASPX page:

dim jss As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

Which spits out the following compiler error:
Type 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer' is not defined.

When I right-click on the project name in Solution explorer and choose property pages one of the references listed is "System.Web.Extensions   GAC   4.0.0.0"

The reference is required according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

So why the H@LL am I getting the "is not defined" error?????????????

Am I missing something obvious (probably -- and if so, please tell ! )

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer does not exist in FrameWork 4.5.1 ?   How does one check?

Anyway, I downloaded and installed the 4.5.2 Framework, set the new build target (to 4.5.2) and viola!